# Get rid of facebook ads

Tags: facebook, sony-xperia, ads

I have a Sony Xperia M4 Acqua. I was wondering if there is a way to get rid of facebook ads in my smartphone, something not seen in my desktop pc due to my using of adblock software. Is there something similar for smartphones?

The device is not rooted and the Android version is 5.0. I see those ads as a separate post on my profile. I'm mostly concerned with these ads inside the Facebook app, as I usually don't surf the web with my mobile.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. We need much more details to give good answers: Where are you seeing those ads? What is the Android version running on your Acqua? Is the device rooted? You can find [Ad-Blocker & Filter](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_adblocker#group_367) in my app lists, but most of them will require your device to be rooted.

Comment: [AdBlock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/en/) doesn't require root but works only on Wi-Fi. See if it helps.

Comment: [Here are the steps to get rid of facebook ads easily!](http://www.the247tech.com/how-to/how-to-get-rid-of-facebook-ads/ "Here are the steps to get rid of facebook ads easily!!")